# Difference between labelsep and lablesep*

Tags: enumitem

Despite careful reading of the documentation, I can't find any examples where replacing `labelsep*` with `labelsep` changes anything. So if anyone can enlighten me, I would be very grateful.

For an example, the following two codes give the same result:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{description}[labelindent=4mm ,labelwidth=1.3cm, labelsep=1em, leftmargin =!, style = standard]
\item[foo] bar
\end{description}

\begin{description}[labelindent=4mm ,labelwidth=1.3cm, labelsep*=1em, leftmargin =!, style = standard]
\item[foo] bar
\end{description}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please always try make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem. I have done it for you in this case.

Comment: When `itemindent` is not 0.

Comment: @JavierBezos can you give me an example where the use of labelsep* is useful?